# Why in the A-star algorithm h(x) is subtracted if heuristic function h is monotonic?

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, a-star

Maybe I am missing something very easy and obvious.

But, I don't understand why estimate cost of source vertex is subtracted from the overall estimate cost, if heuristic function`h` is monotonic(consistent):

Monotonic function: `f(x) = g(x) + h(x)`
Non-monotonic function: `d'(x, y) = d(x, y) + h(y) − h(x)`

**UPD**:

**I was confused and totally misunderstood monotonic/non-monotonic heuristics. [@david-aisenstat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189904/why-in-the-a-star-algorithm-hx-is-subtracted-if-heuristic-function-h-is-monoto/54191819#54191819) helped me to make corrections to the question:**

A* algorithm can be used as an extension for Dijkstra's algorithm. At each iteration of its main loop, it chooses the vertex with the minimum of estimation cost plus cost of the path to this vertex:

For vertex `u` and its successor `v`, overall cost is calculated with formula `f(u, v) = d(u, v) + h(v)` using some heuristic function `h`. Where:

- `d(u,v)` cost of the path from `u` to `v`
- `h(v)` estimate cost from `v` to the target vertex `t`

If for any adjacent vertices `u` and `v`, it is true that `h(u) <= d(u, v) + h(v)` then `h` is a monotonic. In other words, graph holds [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) property.

It is stated in Wiki page of [A* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=A*_search_algorithm&oldid=877587350#Description):

> If the heuristic h satisfies the additional condition h(x) ≤ d(x, y) + h(y) for every edge (x, y) of the graph (where d denotes the length of that edge), then h is called monotone, or consistent. In such a case, A* can be implemented more efficiently—roughly speaking, no node needs to be processed more than once (see closed set below)—and A* is equivalent to running Dijkstra's algorithm with the reduced cost d'(x, y) = d(x, y) + h(y) − h(x).

My questions are:

> and A* is equivalent to running Dijkstra's algorithm with the reduced cost d'(x, y) = d(x, y) + h(y) − h(x).

Any proof for this equivalence ?

It is clear that `0 <= d(x, y) + h(y) - h(x)`, and it is feasible. But:

- Why this formula is chosen as a new distance function ?
- Is there any formal proof that it works ?
- Why it is not enough to run Dijkstra with d'(x, y) = d(x, y) + h(y) ?
- What is the math behind it ?

Answer (score 2):

The condition that you have labeled "Non monotonic" is actually the condition for being monotonic. The equation under "Monotonic" is how to derive a new distance function, `d'`, that incorporates a consistent heuristic `h` into `d`. You can then run Dijkstra on `d'`, which doesn't look at `h` except through the value of `d'`.

The pseudocode for A* in Wikipedia omits the subtraction because it's about the general admissible heuristic case, which uses `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)` as the lower bound on the cost of a solution that uses node `n` via a path that costs `g(n)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it is clearer for me. But I still can't comprehend why two formulas are equivalent if the graph holds triangle inequality property: `f(n) = g(n) + h(n) => f'(n) = d'(n-1, n) + h(n)` where `d'(x,y) = d(x,y) - h(x) + h(y)`

Comment: @maksadbek They aren't. `d'` is the distance function which would be used by the equivalent Dijkstra algorithm. That is, doing A* with `d` and `h` is equivalent to doing Dijkstra with `d'` (and no `h`).

Comment: @Sneftel now I got it. Thank you.